# Who (owner/ writer)needs to pay the option assignment fees

Tags: option-exercise, brokerage, options-assignment

When an option is exercised, there is an option assignment fee that needs to be paid to the (broker/clearing house)?

So if the options expire worthless, this fee need not be paid. But in the case of exercising, this fee needs to be paid by the person that is exercising the option (current owner) or the original writer of the option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of Schwab, my covered call was exercised :

[image]

And I pay a commission same as if I sold it.

Answer (score 1):

Fees are broker-specific.

In [the case of Interactive Brokers](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=commission&p=options1), no fees are charged for many exchanges to assign or exercise.